# ng test doesn't work on hybrid Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I'm working on a hybrid Angular project (both Angular and AngularJS in the same project).
Both the `grunt serve` and `grunt test` commands work fine.
But it fails when I try to run `ng test` to run unit tests of Angular.

It shows errors:

```
./src/app/ui/admin/Ggadmin.component.ts:140:21-74 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ui/admin/ggadmin.component.css' in 'D:\Work\MyApp\src\app\ui\admin'

./src/app/ui/admin/Ggadmin.component.ts:140:21-74 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ui/admin/ggadmin.component.html' in 'D:\Work\MyApp\src\app\ui\admin'
```

`ggadmin.component.ts`, `ggadmin.component.css`, `ggadmin.component.html` and `ggadmin.component.spec.ts` are in the same folder.

And this is `ggadmin.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ggadmin',
    templateUrl: 'ui/admin/cpgadmin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['ui/admin/cpgadmin.component.css']
})
export class GgadminComponent implements OnInit {
```

This is how I downgrade the component to use it in AngularJS (in `app-bootstrap.ts`)

```
angular.module('ui.common', [])
    .directive(
        'ggadmin', downgradeComponent({ component: GgadminComponent }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
    )
```

This is `ggadmin.component.spec.ts`:

```
describe('GadminComponent', () => {
  let component: GgadminComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GgadminComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ GgadminComponent ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GgadminComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I changed `templateUrl` from absolute path to relative path.
It still doesn't work.